# How to configure extra buttons in Logitech Mouse

Tags: mouse, logitech, button

Can anyone tell me how to configure *all* the buttons on a [Logitech MX 620 mouse](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/support/mice/2987) under Ubuntu 12.04?

Specifically, I like to make one of them just the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key (for control clicking webpages) and another one <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to close tabs.  I also normally make the scroll wheel page down for each click (otherwise it hurts my arms to be scrolling so much).  I make pushing the wheel to the left = pageback and pushing to the right = page forward.

I've searched for other answers to this and found something related [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1789807)

But when I posted a followup post to solve the issue, no one responded --perhaps I made the mistake of posting to a question that had been "solved."  I'm not sure how I'm supposed to reopen a question that is pertinent to my question but doesn't quite solve mine.

Comment: I think this is the easiest way to get the mouse working with full functionality:
http://www.ralf-oechsner.de/opensource/page/logitech_performance_mx

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=seDYxGhrc4A

Answer (score 106):

You're going to need several applications for this, to install them run

```
# Ubuntu 14.04 and newer
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys xautomation x11-utils
```

or

```
# Before Ubuntu 14.04
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys xautomation xev
```

(`xev` was merged into x11utils, as of Ubuntu 14.04 or greater)

## Step 1

You need to find the button numbers for the buttons on your mouse.  Run `xev`.  You will see a litle white windows appear, put your mouse in it and press your mouse buttons (it's best to do this one button at a time).  You should get output like this for each button:

```
ButtonRelease event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
root 0x2e9, subw 0x4c00002, time 25804905, (31,28), root:(821,80),
state 0x110, button 1, same_screen YES
```

(note: `xev` also capture mouse movement so you might need to sift through mouse movement events to find your button events; e.g.: `xev -event mouse | grep Button --before-context=1 --after-context=2`)

This is what is important from that output: `button 1`.  That tells us that particular button is button one.  I would store this in a `.txt` file for now.

## Step 2

Create the `xbindkeys` config file using:

```
xbindkeys --defaults > $HOME/.xbindkeysrc
```

Next we need to add the key/button bindings to the config file.  You can open this file with `gedit $HOME/.xbindkeysrc`.  This is where the fun begins.  We are going to use `xte` to set bindings to our buttons.

To make a button act as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> we would add:

```
"xte 'key Control_L'"
b:1
```

This would bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to mouse button one.

If you will tell me the button numbers of your buttons and what you want each to do, I will write the script for you.

Comment: @seth: I would like to configure buttons 8 & 9 to be "back" and "forward" respectively. Better yet, if I could figure out where to fint the commands that I can configure with xbindkeys, that would be great. Thanks,
Dan

Comment: The easiest way to reduce the insanity of the xev output is by running the output through grep: `xev | grep -A2 ButtonPress` ; this will leave all the mouse motion events, focus events, etc. and just show the `ButtonPress` events.

Comment: @dbbd Apparently I missed your message somehow. I will look into it and get back to you.

Comment: @dbbd Whoa, sorry I never got back to you. Can you clarify what you mean by "back" and "forward"? Arrow keys? Home/End? Or do you mean back and forward like in a browser? Thanks and sorry for taking so long.

Comment: My mouse is also a G300 and I can't get this to work. The buttons are incorrectly mapped and two buttons are mapped to the same Control_L button and I have no idea how to map them since when pressed they don't identify themselves.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and I have a Logitech G300, and `xev` doesn't work with it. Under Windows, I had configured the extra buttons to be nothing, and back in `xev`, it can't detect these buttons at all.

Comment: Yeah, it really depends on how you have configured the buttons in windows. I have a G700 and If you unassign all the buttons then xev does not recognize anything on linux. I ended up configuring the buttons in windows and storing the configurations on the mouse's internal memory and now I have all the functions I need in linux. The only drawback is that I can't make any changes to this and if I need to change something I have to boot on windows and make changes there

Comment: "xbindkeys -p"  to apply the changes

Comment: I'm on Kubuntu 16.04, and the characterization of side buttons via `xev` does not work for some of them (basically the MMO specific buttons 1 throught 12 of the UtechSmart Venus mouse). Any idea on why `xev` is failing to recognize those actions?

Comment: @titus.andronicus it would have to do with the manufacture of the mouse. Sometimes buttons are not implemented in the standard ways.

Comment: I have managed to make this working for my logitech mx518. Had to use `b:9 + Release` and `b:8 + Release` with, for example ctrl+w:  `"xte 'usleep 1000' 'keydown Control_L' 'key W' 'keyup Control_L'"`

Comment: For those who don't want to install unnecessary packages: Each entry in `.xbindkeyrc` is generally of the form `"<shell command>"\n<key spec>`. Thus, you don't necessarily have to use `xte`; you can use any command you like. And note `xbindkeys --defaults > $HOME/.xbindkeysrc` sets some default shortcuts (e.g. `Ctrl+f` to run `xterm`) which you may want to comment out. As usual, [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys) is extremely helpful.

Comment: On windows I had a button set to play / pause. Does someone know, how to do this?

Comment: Do No forget to use these commands  killall xbindkeys
xbindkeys and restart/logout  .For me when i restarted my pc the changes took place

Answer (score 29):

The best answer in 2021 is **Input Remapper** (formerly Key Mapper):
https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper

No more hacking required.

**2023 update:**

One potential problem with this tool is that it installs a background service that registers a dummy game controller to achieve the key mapping functionality.

Unfortunately, this can trick some games to use that controller instead of mouse & keyboard. This can (rarely) cause some games that don't have internal controller settings to become unplayable until this service is shut off.

You can temporarily disable the remapper service using:

```
sudo systemctl stop input-remapper.service
```

Re-enable with:

```
sudo systemctl start input-remapper.service
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It's not compatible with Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: That screenshot is from Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Thanks. I had some errors when trying to build it from source but installing from the released deb package is fine. Amazing GUI tool.

Comment: input-remapper also works as designed on Ubuntu 22.04.
v1.4 is in default apt repositories and works without issue with Logitch M510.

The project releases page currently has 5 updates since v1.4, but v1.4 works fine out-of-the-box for my needs. Thanks for this tip. 

https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper/releases

Answer (score 23):

I followed the [@Seth's](https://askubuntu.com/a/246849/74461) instructions, but the binding I wanted was to for the thumb button an the M705 to do `CTRL + Left-click` (for opening links in a new tab in chrome browser). The binding I needed to add was this:

```
"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'mouseclick 1' 'keyup Control_L'"
    b:10 + Release
```

It waits for the thumb button to be released, and then presses control key, performs the mouse click, then releases the control key.

Comment: This solution, not the above, worked like a charm on Ubuntu Mate 16.04 with Logitech M705 mouse. 

I've used it to assign copy and paste to side buttons so my settings looked like this:

"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key c' 'keyup Control_L'"
  b:9
 
"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key v' 'keyup Control_L'"
  b:8

Comment: "xbindkeys -p" to apply the changes.

Answer (score 14):

For anyone who wants to bind copy and paste actions to mouse buttons:

1. Follow Seth answer (the one with Step 1, Step 2 and `sudo apt-get install xbindkeys xautomation xev`)
2. Put following lines in your `.xbindkeysrc` file:

This is for copying:

```
"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key c' 'keyup Control_L'"
b:9
```

This is for pasting:

```
"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key v' 'keyup Control_L'"
b:8
```

*`b:9` means button 9 on the mouse (check button numbers with `xev`)

3. It won't work right away, you must reload `.xbindkeysrc` first or restart your machine.

Comment: oh wow this worked for me perfectly. trying to set up those keys for the past 4 years and only now able to do this. thank you! btw it is super important to know what buttons those are, for me they were 16 and 17 on my mouse..

Comment: NOTE: the b:9 etc HAVE TO be on a new line in the config file. I put them on the same line and couldn't work out why it wasn't working.

Comment: This worked for me for the GUI, but it doesn't work for the Bash terminal. Is there any way to make copy/paste work for BOTH the GUI and the shell with the same buttons?

Comment: @JoeMjr2 In Bash terminal you most probably would paste using Ctrl+Shift+V and copy by pressing Ctrl+Shift+C. So you would need some way to use application-specific mapping. I am not sure how though. Maybe you could use some terminal emulator and set up hotkeys to copy paste the standard way - then your copy paste mouse buttons should work.

Comment: one can get example of xbindkeys configuration by running: $ xbindkeys --defaults

Comment: also one can read this [tutorial:](http://xahlee.info/linux/linux_xbindkeys_tutorial.html)

Comment: The point number 3 worked for me after i restarted my pc it started working thank you

Answer (score 4):

You should install Solaar, a Linux tool that allows you to manage Logitech Unifying Receiver mice and keyboards, that comes with both a GUI and command line interface. To do that add the following repository and install by executing the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:daniel.pavel/solaar

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install solaar
```

This will allow you to increase and maximize you mouse's DPI, monitor battery, enable smooth scrolling and side scrolling. To get the multi window and zoom button working you can visit this site which walks you through the easy steps to get the functionality you are looking for:

http://www.ralf-oechsner.de/opensource/page/logitech_performance_mx

Comment: I did this on my C720/crouton. When I ran solaar, it crashed back to the start screen. I had to restart (and figure out the command was sudo startxfce4) and removed solaar.

Comment: Solaar was very buggy for me on 14.04 and eventually just wouldn't run at all. I realize the original question was about 12.04, but thought it was worth mentioning. Maybe save someone some time.

Comment: -1. This answer does not answer the question. solaar does not do any mapping of the mouse buttons.

Comment: didnt work for me either.

Answer (score 4):

You should already have these as they should come with Ubuntu, but run this just in case.

```
sudo apt-get install libdaemon-dev libglade2-dev libgtk2.0-dev
```

Now, download & install

1. [btnx-config](https://github.com/cdobrich/btnx-config)
2. [btnx](https://github.com/cdobrich/btnx) In this order.

To install:

Unzip, and `cd` into each of these folders.

In each of them run:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Once both of them are installed, run

```
sudo btnx-config
```

In Configurations tab, click Detect Mouse & Buttons

[image]

In Buttons tab, assign your mouse button a key or functionality. **Make sure you ☑ check mark enabled**.

[image]

Lastly, in Configurations tab, click on Restart btx button so your changes take effect.

[image]

Comment: Worked well on ubuntu disco. One correction: It should be just `./configure`, not `./configure make`. Also you don't need sudo with make.

Comment: @panta82 I took those directly from the  README.md file

Comment: I know. There is a mistake in the README file :)

Comment: So this didn't quite work for me as it didn't override the defaults so each mouse button press resulted in two inputs, ie 1p, 2l, 3, (where the numbers are the defaults and letters are new binds)

Comment: Still can't use DPI change buttons.

Answer (score 3):

I too have the g700s gaming mouse.  The good news is that it was expensive (for a mouse) and the manufacture actually built it to a high standard.  The functions for the mouse are stored in the mouse.  The bad news is to configure it correctly you need to use the logitech software that only runs in windows.

So...**basically you need to plug the mouse into a windows box, and configure it exactly how you want it**.  I'd recommend utilizing the switch profiles function so you can set it up good for normal usage, ie: running your linux desktop, compiz functions (switching apps, switching workspaces, toggling maximize, etc), and then make another profile for gaming (possibly with a different refresh rate) and the gaming buttons.  As for compiz consider setting the 4 side thumbs buttons to alt, ctl, shift, superkey, as this will make using switching easier with the scroll wheel.  alt + scroll wheel up becomes thumb button 1 + scroll wheel up.

My scheme:

thumb button 1 (forward lower) = alt

thumb button 2 (forward upper) = shift

thumb button 3 (rear lower) = ctrl

thumb button 4 (rear upper) = superkey (windows key)

index finger middle button = ctrl + alt + numpad 5

index finger closer to you = tab

index finger farther away from you = alt-f4 (compiz/linux/winX close app)

compiz defaults:

switch workspace = alt + ctl + mouse drag = lower 2 thumb buttons together + mouse click and drag; sounds complicated when typed it out but it's very efficient to use.

switch apps = alt + tab = lower thumb forward button + index finger closer button (remember for this to work well you need to keep holding down thumb button, so you can switch past 1 app)

fading a window (transparency) = alt + scroll wheel = thumb lower forward button + scroll wheel

Then go haul it back over to your linux box and it works perfectly.

The key bindings described above works great, but consider battlefield 4 also has a terrible time recognizing the mouse as a mouse with 10 buttons so for that I had to map my 4 thumb buttons to = , \ and ;.  But obviously in linux this is silly, and to re-bind the = key to "next app" is a lesson in futility, especially when coding hahahaha.

**MUCH NEEDED LINKS IF USING VIRTUALBOX TO RUN WINDOWS 7:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021300/usb-devices-are-not-recognized-in-virtualbox-linux-host

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-0OyrvbZNwo

Answer (score 2):

I think https://github.com/sezanzeb/key-mapper will most likely be able to do it in that case.

Comment: Finally a GUI that "just works". Thanks very much for your tool!

Comment: Its name has changed to "Input Remapper" but it is also available in Ubuntu Software from universe repo.

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to do something similar, and I've come across this page:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=65471

Hopefully it works for mx 620 as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Logitech MX 500 and wanted to map the lateral keys with Copy and Paste actions (it is very useful).

I used [this](http://hanschen.org/2009/10/13/mouse-shortcuts-with-xbindkeys/) guide to understand how to configure the xbindkeysrc file and be able to map the keys.

Comment: You know that moving the mouse pointer to the start/end of the text you want to copy and then press down the left button and keep holding it till you get to the end/start of what you want to copy and it's copied. When you want to paste you press the middle button (if you just have a two button mouse, press both left and right button at the same time) and you paste the text. No need to configure anything, this is out of the box on all Unix and Linux machines with a XWindows System. Please keep in mind we ain't using a featureless microsoft product but GNU/Linux

Comment: @user350566 This kind of copy+paste has some limitations. Sometimes you want the other clipboard aka Ctrl+C / +V. Just saying.

Answer (score 1):

I made a solution that works with Wayland.

Its here https://github.com/mathportillo/wayland-mouse-mapper

It uses evemu to send a device event notice to the kernel, so it's not restricted by Wayland

A summarized bash script that show how it works is below (most of the commands require root privileges)

find your device:

```
libinput list-devices
```

to directly find your pointer device name use:

```
libinput list-devices | grep pointer -B3 | grep -o '/dev/input/event[1-9]*'
```

to list your device events use (change event5 to your pointer device name):

```
libinput debug-events --device /dev/input/event5
```

to bind commands to your device events use:

```
while read line; do
    echo ${line} # line represents a command
    # your code goes here
done < <(stdbuf -oL libinput debug-events --device /dev/input/event5 & )
```

to trigger a mouse event use:

```
evemu-event /dev/input/event5 --sync --type EV_KEY --code KEY_PAGEUP --value 1
```

type can be other than keystroke, and code can be other than PageUp, value is 1 for pressed and 0 for released
yes, your mouse can trigger keystrokes, the system will interpret it the same as keyboards, its all just events from event devices.

A script that merge all the above concepts on a working mapper, that works on Wayland and can be configured as a service to start on system startup, can be found in the git repo above.

Answer (score 1):

## Scroll up and down with mouse forward and back buttons

First, install the required packages:

```
$ sudo apt install x11-utils xbindkeys xautomation
```

Next, use `xev` provided by `x11-utils` to detect the exact button numbers of the back and forward buttons of the mouse.

```
$ xev |grep -A2 ButtonPress
```

For my [wired vertical Anker mouse](https://www.anker.com/products/variant/anker-ergonomic-optical-usb-wired-vertical-mouse/A7851011), back and forward are respectively buttons 8 and 9.

```
ButtonPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3600001,
    root 0x1da, subw 0x0, time 1708382, (68,54), root:(939,498),
    state 0x10, button 8, same_screen YES
--
ButtonPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3600001,
    root 0x1da, subw 0x0, time 1711030, (69,48), root:(940,492),
    state 0x10, button 9, same_screen YES
```

[image: wired vertical Anker mouse]

Continue by creating a hidden file named `.xbindkeysrc` in your home directory with the following contents:

```
"xte 'keydown Down'"
b:8

"xte 'keyup Down'"
b:8 + Release

"xte 'keydown Up'"
b:9

"xte 'keyup Up'"
b:9 + Release
```

The `xte` command is provided by the `xautomation` package.

Finally, **log out** and in again from the desktop for these changes to take effect. You can now scroll up and down in browsers and other programs by pressing and holding the mouse back and forward buttons.

Answer (score 0):

in Debian you have a `xbindkeys-config` package which will help you configure your key/button bindings. So do:

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys-config
```

Comment: That program just crashes whenever I try to do anything with my G300.

Comment: I think `xbindkeys-config` works reasonably well. But all my mouse buttons arent captured by it, it only works with keyboard key strokes.

Answer (score 0):

So I have been using my performance MX on my ubuntu machine for about 6 months. I left most buttons default, but I did go ahead and make the thumb button the Super key which is handier than going to the top left corner of the screen in gnome. And I made the zoom button a control button. But it is set to turn on CTRL and turn off CTRL with separate clicks. This really helps since I have one 4K display and one 1080, so I can click the zoom button once, scroll the wheel to zoom in and out fo web pages, and when I have the web page scaled how I want, I click the zoom again. Here is my xbindkeysrc settings:

```
"/usr/bin/xte 'keydown Control_L' &"
b:13
"/usr/bin/xte 'keyup Control_L' &"
Control + b:13
"/usr/bin/xte 'key Super_L'"
b:10 + release
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

Lomoco is included in Ubuntu Software Center and specifically is designed to deal with Logitech Mouse vendor-specific customizations.  It can possibly accomplish some of the things you are trying to do.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/lomoco.1.html

Comment: doesn't work for the G700

Answer (score 0):

`btnx` might be a simple solution for button remapping with Logitech mouses as it should be working with all brands. It has an easy graphical interface and can learn about available buttons. btnx was part of the standard repositories years ago, but has been removed. It is currently available here: https://launchpad.net/~oliverstar/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add **CTRL+Home** and **CTRL+End** you add following lines:

```
#CTRL + Home (Go to top of the page)
"xte 'keydown Control_R' 'key Home' 'keyup Control_R'"
  b:6

#CTRL + End (Go to down of the page)
"xte 'keydown Control_R' 'key End' 'keyup Control_R'"
  b:7
```

---

PS:

to find your mouse key code:

```
 xev | grep button
```

to test your shortcut:

```
killall  xbindkeys && xbindkeys -n -v
```