# mouse back button brings up run command box after sending "back" command

Tags: shortcut-keys, mouse

[Relevant, didn't help much though.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236529/binding-back-forward-to-mouse-buttons)

I've got a RAT 7 that I'm using in Ubuntu. It's working fine, but for some reason when I hit the "back" button it will output Alt Left and then bring up the 'run command' box. Alt Left looks like "^[[1;3D" in bash. In Chrome it will send the "back" command to the browser, then bring up the run command box, like it's hitting Alt Left then Alt F2. Well not exactly like Alt F2, the box looks similar but is smaller, it's just the text box.

You can see what happens after I click the back button here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/suFeV.jpg (see upper left). Happens in bash as well.

I've tried using `xinput test` but it doesn't seem to be capturing.

I'm running Ubuntu in a VM. I have a right/left wheel on the mouse as well and it is working fine. I've tested the back button in the mouse's config and it's not outputting anything other than Alt Left.

It's not a big deal but I would like to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Solution to this was to increase the amount of time that the Alt Key was held down in the mouse's software. As it was, the Alt key was being "bounced" and that brings up a little "Run" dialog. You have to get the mouse to hold down Alt for a bit longer to get it to work.