# Mouse wheel side buttons not working

Tags: mouse, mouse-wheel

I am trying to get the side buttons of the wheel of my mouse (Logitech Bluetooth mouse V470) to work in Ubuntu 17.10.
It used to work on Ubuntu 16.04 under imwheel (on another machine).

This is my current configuration:

```
$ cat .imwheelrc  
".*" 
None, Left, Alt_L|Left 
None, Right, Alt_L|Right

$ cat /etc/X11/imwheel/startup.conf
IMWHEEL_START=0
IMWHEEL_PARAMS='-b "6 7"'
```

What is wrong with it?

Thank you

Comment: Try [switching back to Xorg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961304/how-do-you-switch-from-wayland-back-to-xorg-in-ubuntu-17-10) if you're in Wayland.

Comment: Already in Xorg sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by following [this procedure](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236529/binding-back-forward-to-mouse-buttons?rq=1).

Still would like to know why imwheel doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

You should already have these as they should come with Ubuntu, but run this just in case.

```
sudo apt-get install libdaemon-dev libglade2-dev libgtk2.0-dev
```

Now, download & install

1) [btnx-config](https://github.com/cdobrich/btnx-config)
2) [btnx](https://github.com/cdobrich/btnx) In this order.

To install:

Unzip, and `cd` into each of these folders.

In each of them run:

```
./configure make
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Once both of them are installed, run

```
sudo btnx-config
```

In Configurations tab, click Detect Mouse & Buttons

[image]

In Buttons tab, assign your mouse button a key or functionality. **Make sure you ☑ check mark enabled**.

[image]

Lastly, in Configurations tab, click on Restart btx button so your changes take effect.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I no longer use that mouse nor that Ubuntu version. Anyway, this answer may be useful to other people.

Comment: Indeed @LastStarDust. I'm actually using 18.04, but looks to me that btnx works for any version. I spent countless of hours trying to get `xev | grep button` to recognise my side buttons by modifying the xorg.conf, but never got it to work. While my mouse is Logitech, I believe btnx will work with any mouse brand.