# How can I bind logitech mx anywhere side scroll button press to raise and lower volume

Tags: mouse, logitech, shortcut-keys, xev

I have a logitech MX anywhere (on a thinkpad t480s if that matters) and I have tried following guides like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236529/binding-back-forward-to-mouse-buttons) but I can't seem to get it working. I basically want to control volume down and volume up with the mouse scroll wheel left click and scroll wheel right click respectively. I would appreciate any help with the respectively.

Comment: Wuttt? I've had an MX mouse for years and I never realized the scrollwheel could also do a left-click or right-click! I thought the left-right movement was just due to shoddy quality :-)

Answer (score 0):

depending on your desktop environment

first bind a random keyboard shortcut in Settings->Keyboard->Application Shortcuts to:
`amixer set Master 5%+ 
 amixer set Master 5%-`

then bind the keyboard shortcut to a button
for that try BTNX-Config. It works great.

https://github.com/cdobrich/btnx/blob/master/INSTALL

download, make, install.

> 1. cd' to the directory containing the package's source code and type
>       ./configure to configure the package for your system.
>
>    Running configure might take a while.  While running, it prints
>       some messages telling which features it is checking for.
> 2. Type make to compile the package.
> 3. Optionally, type make check to run any self-tests that come with
>       the package.
> 4. Type make install to install the programs and any data files and
>       documentation.
> 5. You can remove the program binaries and object files from the
>       source code directory by typing make clean.  To also remove the
>       files that configure created (so you can compile the package for
>       a different kind of computer), type make distclean.  There is
>       also a make maintainer-clean target, but that is intended mainly
>       for the package's developers.  If you use it, you may have to get
>       all sorts of other programs in order to regenerate files that came
>       with the distribution.