# Solaar + Ubuntu how to set volume up/down to forward/backward buttons on logitech mx master 2s

Tags: bluetooth, mouse, logitech

I have a logitech mx master 2s that I connected to my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, using solaar. I try to change the key mapping so that the forward/backward buttons are volume up/down. However, the only options in key mappings that come up in solaar is "mouse forward button", "left click", "right click", and "mouse back button".

I was previously using KDE, which allowed me to set a system shortcut to whatever the forward/backward buttons registered to. However, GNOME seems to have only keyboard shortcuts.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: Related: [How can I bind logitech mx anywhere side scroll button press to raise and lower volume](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1118840/how-can-i-bind-logitech-mx-anywhere-side-scroll-button-press-to-raise-and-lower)

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/101105/307523