# Configure Logitech mouse with xbindkeys

Tags: mouse, logitech, xbindkeys

I have a Logitech Performance MX mouse I want to configure for Ubuntu 14.10 using xbindkeys. I managed to install xbindkeys and xautomation following [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152297/how-to-configure-extra-buttons-in-logitech-mouse), however, the buttons still don't work.

Here is my xbindkeysrc file:

```
# For the benefit of emacs users: -*- shell-script -*-
###########################
# xbindkeys configuration #
###########################
#
# Version: 1.8.6
#
# If you edit this file, do not forget to uncomment any lines
# that you change.
# The pound(#) symbol may be used anywhere for comments.
#
# To specify a key, you can use 'xbindkeys --key' or
# 'xbindkeys --multikey' and put one of the two lines in this file.
#
# The format of a command line is:
#    "command to start"
#       associated key
#
#
# A list of keys is in /usr/include/X11/keysym.h and in
# /usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h
# The XK_ is not needed.
#
# List of modifier:
#   Release, Control, Shift, Mod1 (Alt), Mod2 (NumLock),
#   Mod3 (CapsLock), Mod4, Mod5 (Scroll).
#

# The release modifier is not a standard X modifier, but you can
# use it if you want to catch release events instead of press events

# By defaults, xbindkeys does not pay attention with the modifiers
# NumLock, CapsLock and ScrollLock.
# Uncomment the lines above if you want to pay attention to them.

#keystate_numlock = enable
#keystate_capslock = enable
#keystate_scrolllock= enable

# Examples of commands:

"xbindkeys_show" 
  control+shift + q

# set directly keycode (here control + f with my keyboard)
#"xterm"
#  c:41 + m:0x4

# specify a mouse button
#"xterm"
#  control + b:2

#"xterm -geom 50x20+20+20"
#   Shift+Mod2+alt + s
#
## set directly keycode (here control+alt+mod2 + f with my keyboard)
#"xterm"
#  alt + c:0x29 + m:4 + mod2
#
## Control+Shift+a  release event starts rxvt
#"rxvt"
#  release+control+shift + a
#
## Control + mouse button 2 release event starts rxvt
#"rxvt"
#  Control + b:2 + Release

"xte 'key Control_L'"
b:10 

##################################
# End of xbindkeys configuration #
##################################
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include your `.xbindkeysrc` file?

Comment: @Seth, I've included my .xbindkeysrc file. I understand that 'key Control_L' is left Ctrl. But pressing button 10 on the mouse and, say, the key 'Q' to quit an application doesn't work. I've also tried under key combinations. I'd like to set button 10 to Super + W (Expose). Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Is this `"xte 'key Control_L'"
b:10` what doesn't work? What do you expect that to do?

Comment: this tutorial helped me a lot https://blog.hanschen.org/2009/10/13/mouse-shortcuts-with-xbindkeys/

Comment: I can't believe mapping mouse buttons is still an issue in 2017. Don't muck around with xev xte nonsense Why not use Btnx: [main daemon](https://github.com/cdobrich/btnx)
[Config GUI](https://github.com/cdobrich/btnx-config) Install it quick and easy per instructions here:
http://awesomelinux.blogspot.com/2012/08/btnx-for-ubuntu-1204-precise.html

Answer (score 3):

I know this questions is a year old, but it still seems to be unanswered.

I think your problem is that you just trigger `xte 'key Control_L'`, which will just "tap" your control key, meaning the keypress is only emulated for a very short amount of time and then the key is released. You need to issue a `keydown` event when you start pressing the mouse button and fire a `keyup` event when you release the mouse button. Your `.xbindkeysrc` should look like this:

```
"xte 'keydown Control_L'"
    b:10

"xte 'keyup Control_L'"
    b:10 + Release
```

Answer (score 2):

I found that xte is flakey.
My sequence for mapping the the thumb button of my logitech 518 to 'control W' to close tabs and windows never worked well with xte not sequencing properly.
For example this failed:

```
"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'w' 'keyup Control_L'"
 b:8
```

as did this:

```
"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'w' 'keyup Control_L'"
 b:8 + release
```

I also noticed that xte was slow.
I tried xvkbd and it works well.

of course you have to get xvkbd with this:

```
sudo apt-get install xvkbd
```

Put this in your `.xbindkeysrc` file in your home directory

```
"xvkbd  -text '\C\[w]'"
m:0x0 + b:8
```

and restart xbindkeys

```
pkill -f xbindkeys && xbindkeys
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a Logitech M705 and just went through this.

Button 8 maps to the forward/backward button on the side:

```
###########################
# xbindkeys configuration #
###########################
# Workspace Left
 "xte 'keydown Control_L' 'keydown Alt_L' 'key Left' 'keyup Alt_L' 'keyup Control_L'"
  b:8
##################################
# End of xbindkeys configuration #
##################################
```

Answer (score 0):

Must be because the key control by itself does not do much.

Try this:

```
xte 'keydown Super_L' 'keydown Right' 'keyup Super_L' 'keyup Right'
```

This is basically `Super[windows key]+Right_Arrow` that must take any open window to the right half part of your screen.

This is just an example, you can automate any keys combination.

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble mapping my mouse buttons too.  None of the existing answers here got to the heart of the issue.

TL;DR: Add the `+ release` association to the mapping (see last code snippet).

As an example, I wanted to show the window overview, which I was trying to do with this:

```
"/usr/bin/dbus-send --session --print-reply --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.overview.toggle();'"
  b:8
```

I added some logging to confirm `xbindkeys` was picking up the presses, which it was:

```
"echo 'b:8 pressed' > /tmp/.xbindkeys.log 2>&1"
  b:8
```

So given the key presses were working I knew the issue wasn't with `xbindkeys` picking up the presses, but somewhere else.  I tried with simulating key presses with `xte`, but this also didn't work.  However I noticed that something odd was going on with the focus of windows on the screen when I did this.

```
"/usr/bin/xte 'keydown Super_L' 'key s' 'keyup Super_L' >> /tmp/.xbindkeys.log 2>&1"
  b:8
```

As a stab in the dark I added the `+ release` association to the command, which resolved the issue:

```
"/usr/bin/xte 'keydown Super_L' 'key s' 'keyup Super_L' >> /tmp/.xbindkeys.log 2>&1"
  b:8 + release
```

Given key assignments can change, using `xte` isn't a robust solution, so I wanted to go back to the `dbus-send` command.  So swapping out the commands and including the `+ release` association, everything worked right:

```
"/usr/bin/dbus-send --session --print-reply --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'Main.overview.toggle();'"
  b:8 + release
```

In hindsight I found a reference to this solution in the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys#Troubleshooting).  Can anyone can shed light on why `+ release` is needed in the comments?