# How to install a Logitech G402 Hyperion Fury mouse?

Tags: drivers, mouse, logitech

How to install a Logitech G402 Hyperion Fury mouse?

I tried the official website but nothing.

Comment: Is your mouse even recognized by your computer? Is it usable? What version of Ubuntu are you using? Have you tried something on your own? What do you mean with "install", it should be recognized once you plug it in and be usable. Do you want to map the extra keys?

Comment: Yes,it's recognized and it's usable,but I don't have extra keys.I use ubuntu 14.04.There is a whole program for it on windows.

Comment: How about this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/152297/how-to-configure-extra-buttons-in-logitech-mouse

Comment: As I have the mouse myself I can state that there indeed is a problem with the mouse buttons (three of them seem to be assigned to internal functions and their presses don't show up anywhere (tried `xev` and `xinput --test`).