# Mouse shortcuts get confused with keyboard keys in Kubuntu

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, shortcut-keys, mouse

I am running Kubuntu 16.04, for which I recently purchased a MMO mouse with many extra buttons (the UtechSmart Venus to be specific).

As those buttons would be of good use, I wanted to map some of them to things as Volume Up / Volume Down / Pause-Play, etc. I started doing so under `System Settings -> Shortcuts` and it worked fine.

The problem is, the bindings are mapped to numbers (e.g. 1 is Volume Up), which in turn also happen on the keyboard. This is undesired!

- Is there a way to *uniquely* map the mouse extra buttons without interfering with the keyboard keys?
- What are other customization options for custom key bindings for the mouse under (K)ubuntu?

I came across https://sourceforge.net/projects/kbmaster/ , but was wondering if there was a way to avoid it. Also not sure if it will work with a mouse instead of a keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use `xbindkeys` , it can bind nearly anything to a key/button press *( if you combine it with `xautomation` can make mouse button clicks from keyboard for example)*.

If you feel uncomfortable with config files maybe you can try using `xbindkeys-config` *(GUI)*.

Also if your mouse buttons are not recognized, you probably need to use the evdev driver. Check [this Ubuntu wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MouseCustomizations#Evdev_Driver) for more info.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I installed and tried to capture the extra buttons as described here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/152297/how-to-configure-extra-buttons-in-logitech-mouse with `xev`. But sadly the extra MMO keys on the side (1..12) are not recognized.. any idea?

Comment: Maybe some problem with your muose driver, you probably need to switch to the evdev driver. I added a link on the answer with more instructions.