# How to access extra mouse buttons on Wayland?

Tags: mouse, wayland, xbindkeys, 21.04

Since unfortunately Gnome does not offer any option to configure additional mouse buttons I used to achieve this simple goal by writing a tedious configuration file for `xbindkeys`.

What I wanted was far from super fancy stuff – as launching a rocket by hitting a mouse button – but only switching workspace by left or right clicking the scroll wheel of my Logitech mouse.

How this is done under Xorg has been answered many times, here for example: [How to configure extra buttons in Logitech Mouse](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152297/how-to-configure-extra-buttons-in-logitech-mouse)

But with Ubuntu 21.04 where – buckle up! – Wayland has become the default display manager, as of now fancy pancy things like `xbindkeys`and `xdotool` do not work anymore.

So my question: is there a way to launch missiles – ehm, sorry switch work spaces with my extra mouse button again? Or should I sell them and donate the money to Gnome Fondation?

Please do not propose `libratbag` and `piper`, I never got them working in any useful way...

Comment: That wayland has become the default (not the first time, btw) doesn't mean that you can't keep using the old xorg.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Rightly said, Sir! And I'm stuck with Xorg for that very reason. But there a indubitably some good reasons to switch to Wayland and the mouse buttons are the hurdle that hundred me to follow them and jump back to the future of Ubuntu 17.10 (was it 17.10?).

Comment: You could install `Solaar`. It has some configuration things for various Logitech mice. Otherwise, some Logitech settings, when set in Windows, carry over to Ubuntu.

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for pointing this out and giving me the guidance  I needed. I edited the question to bring in more in line and removed the thorn I put into communities eye.

Comment: @heynnema does not give me any option to assign an action to the keys other than mouse clicks. For example you can make the scroll wheel do a right or left click and so on.

Comment: Some mice show a rule editor that you might be able to configure.

Comment: @heynnema If some one could show me where to find this editor I would be grateful.

Comment: Go to the Solaar top panel icon, click, and select your mouse from the drop-down menu. A window will open with a Rule Editor button. I have not used it myself. Report back if it helps.

Comment: @heynnema The editor is not available for my mouse (M510) and the [documentation](https://pwr-solaar.github.io/Solaar/rules) says: »Note that rule processing is only available when running under X11.«

Comment: As per my prior comment, try setting something when in Windows (Using the Logitech software), and see if it carries over when you reboot into Ubuntu.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### input-remapper

> An easy to use tool to change the behaviour of your input devices.

The most comfortable solution I found is [`input-remapper`](https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper). This application allows you, to map mouse buttons to shortcuts. I for example use it to switch workspace with the left and right click of my scroll wheel, what fits particularly good with the horizontal layout of workspaces in GNOME 40+:

[image: screemsjpt]

As you can see, the program comes with a GUI.

You can download an official DEB packages from [here](https://github.com/sezanzeb/key-mapper/releases), or installed from terminal [on 22.04+](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/input-remapper).

Comment: Adding to @user5950 's answer, the app is now called input-remapper, in case anyone is still searching about this, like me

Comment: While this works perfectly for my G502 Mouse i would like to know why i do need it to have my basic forward/back functionality working in ubuntu. This is beyond me.