How do I stop the side buttons on my mouse from being "back" and "forward" buttons?
I have a cheap "gaming" mouse.  I can't find a manufacturer website.  It has thumb buttons, which seem to have a system wide "back" and "forward" action.  In Firefox it goes back and forward in history.  In Sublime they scroll through open tabs.  In Nemo it also controls history.
I want to disable all that, because I want to use one as a push to talk key, and don't want using it to have effects in whatever is the focused application.
I have no software suite that goes with the mouse.  Something like dconf, or similar might be the way to go, but I couldn't find the button in the mouse section of dconf.
I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.

I don't have a direct answer, but have you seen this: https://askubuntu.com/a/246849/453950
